# highchart column chart color for same month

Tags: highcharts

I am using this example to draw highchart of column type.
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

The example shows different color combination for month Jan, Feb etc. I am wondering, is it possible to have same color for each month? That is, for each bar in Jan month have same color set say,  red, then Feb, will have color green for each bars and all bars from March will have orange etc.

I tried to find out the way, but unable to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
colorByPoint: true
```

did the trick. This worked for me. You can use this in your series option.
Eg.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Jan',
            data: [10,20,50,60],
            colorByPoint: true,
            color: red
        }, {
            name: 'Feb',
            data: [20,50,30,80],
            colorByPoint: true,
            color: green
        },{
         ....
```

This might be useful for someone.

Comment: I am working the similar chart in R. Could you please share the whole code ? Thank you!

Comment: @czqiu working code : https://jsfiddle.net/9hs50L7c/